# Como realizar uma verificação de data?

Tags: java

Gostaria de saber como faço para verificar se uma data de entrada fornecida pelo usuário é valida ou não.

Comment: A solução que postei era oque você precisava? Não entendi o data de entrada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar essa solução:

```
public class VerificarData {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        sdf.setLenient(false);  
        String dataHoje = "08/12/2014";

        try {
            Date data = sdf.parse(dataHoje);
            System.out.println("A data é válida.");
        } catch(ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("A data é inválida.");
        }
    }
}
```

Essa solução eu uso em uma aplicação aqui e funciona, eu peguei ela no GUJ mas não lembro o link, então o crédito é de quem postou lá.

O setLenient serve para dizer que não pode haver nenhum erro na String, se você colocar por exemplo 10/13/2014 ele vai retornar erro.